# Can an Excel spreadsheet column be indexed like a normal database table column?

Tags: database, performance, excel, indexing

I have a customer trying to use a 75mb Excel spreadsheet as a database. They are resistant to move it to anything else. I am not aware of a way to index an Excel spreadsheet, so I thought I would ask. I did Google "index Excel", but I did not find anything. There seems to be an "index" function in Excel that is unrelated to database indexing (unless I'm reading it wrong).

**EDIT (Additional Info):** A Crystal Report has been written against this spreadsheet and it has 40, yes 40, sub-reports, all going against the same multi-tabbed spreadsheet. It's crazy, but that's how they designed it. It's taking an absurd amount of time to process and if the data were indexed, it would still be slow, but it would 100x's less slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot index an Excel spreadsheet.  The =INDEX() function in Excel is merely a way to get a cell reference and has nothing to do with the "index" that is a defining feature of any RDBMS.  There are reasons that database management systems are expensive and complex, and one of them is because they provide the ability to organize data for fast retrieval and processing.

However, your real problem seems more political than technical! I don't know what kind of time and resources you have available to you, but I would see if you could import this spreadsheet into some kind of free/cheap database(like SQL Server Express, or even Access), and slap together a mock report to demo to the client.  From what you describe, it seems like they really have no idea about the kind of performance they COULD be seeing vs. what they have to deal with now.  If they see a often-used report being generated 50x faster than what they usually see, they might change their minds about Excel.

Answer (score 2):

One option to help with the data side of things would be to use an SSIS task to drop the spreadsheet data nightly (or some interval) into a SQL table and code the report against that - the users still get to update the spreadsheet and you get to leverage some performance for the report.

Your bigger problem in my view is the use of crystal and is two fold:

1: Sub reports will run once per detail row they occur in, so that a single sub report can run dozens or hundreds of times. Even if they're at the top level (one a one per page basis or similar) the overhead of these sub reports is nasty.

2: The crystal engine is not the quickest way of collating data (but would be the only way to do it against the excel sheet).

There are a couple of things you can do about this, but they both involve a bunch of rework:

1: Assuming that you can use my suggestion of transfering the data to SQL, write stored procs to actually product the report data (grouped, sorted, filtered etc etc), and just use the Crystal to display it (rather than having the Crystal engine do everything). This should make a big difference to the performance of each report.

2: If you have lots of reports with the same formatting (ie 4 columns of data and similar graphs), you can combine these in the stored procs in 1, so taht a single stored proc returns data for multiple reports. This reduces the number of trips and number of reports that get rendered. For example your stored proc could return a data set like:

```
ReportName    Col1Name    Col1Value    Col2Name    Col2Value
SubReport1    Name        Joe Bloggs   Orders      12
SubReport1    Name        Jane Bloggs  Orders      7
SubReport2    Product     Trousers     StockLevel  10
SubReport2    Product     Shirts       StockLevel  15
```

The Crystal report can take this data set and make it into sub reports by grouping on the ReportName column. This technique can make it harder to apply report specific formatting though, so it needs to be done with consideration.

I've used both these methods in the past to produce reports that run orders of magnitude faster than the reports on which they were based.